# Setting an A/B test for electronic devices after an update

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design

I want to set up an experimental testing or A/B test.

We have electronic devices on the field. Recently we had a problem with the keydoor. It started falling(it wont open(Fail) after we try to open it). 
Our engineering team upgraded the sensors with a new firmware couple of weeks ago. Now, I want to set up an experiment to conclude if the firmware up-gradation was successful or not. Although we are hearing less complaint from the field seems like it worked but
I want to support/report the claim with statistics. I need some inputs regarding how should i design my test. 
My data looks something like this

```
 DeviceID   Event         Time 
 1          Access        1/1/2019 
 1          success       2/1/2019 
 1          Access        4/1/2019 
 1          fail          5/1/2019 
 1          Access        6/1/2019 
 1          fail          7/1/2019 
 .          .......      .........
```

Let's say we updated the firmware on 6/1/2019.

I have divided my sample into 2 groups before and after the update.

My hypothesis will be : Firmware update was successful/not.

Metrics: count of Fail/ count of Access for 10 access.

Now a simple t-test will be enough to make my decision? Should i look for anything else/ am i missing something? This metrics would be enough ?

Any inputs or related literature will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Several questions: (1) Before the problems started, what was the proportion of Failures? What has the proportion of failures been since the problems started? How much improvement would you view as "success"? (2) What does notation 'something' mean? Ignore those and remove them from data? Count them as failures? (3) Somehow, it seems you want to test for a difference in access rates before and after intervention. Do you want to know how to do the test? Do you want to know how many before & after observations you need in order to distinguish?

Comment: Thanks. 
1. The failure rate was around 20%(fail/access) for every 10 access. It's an average rate of all devices. Since the problem started it went up by 40%. I am expecting it to come down around 20 - 30 % to call it as a success. 
3. I have around 50000 devices. I am thinking to take the data of next 10 access(after the firmware update)  for all of them. Am I right on this approach or Do I need to choose a sample? Also, Do you think if this is a right metric for me to tell how much was the impact?